# How to post process the images after segmentation to get a smoother boundary using OpenCV or any other library?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

Is there any advance technique or a library that can post-process the images for segmentation to give smooth boundaries on segmented part using a mask?

#### [This website here provides very good boundaries](https://www.remove.bg/)

Here is the code which I have adapted the [`combined_display` method in this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P3cWtg8fnmu9karZHYDAtmm1vj1rgA-f?usp=sharing#scrollTo=KDSVmgi67f4I) from the [ModNet Paper](https://github.com/ZHKKKe/MODNet) which is as follows:

```
def overlay_mask(image:np.ndarray, mask:np.ndarray, return_comparison: bool = False)-> np.ndarray:
  '''
  Overlay Mask over Image. Smoothes the image boundry
  image: RGB Numpy array
  mask: Binary B/W mask
  return_comparison: whether to return side by side images for original and new
  '''

  # obtain predicted foreground
  if len(image.shape) == 2: # If grayscale, add empty dimension
    image = image[:, :, None]
    
  if image.shape[2] == 1: # If grayscale with empty dimension, repeat to give the image a RGB look
    image = np.repeat(image, 3, axis=2)
    
  elif image.shape[2] == 4: # if RGBA, Pick first 3 Dimensions
    image = image[:, :, 0:3]
    
  # mask = np.repeat(mask[:, :, None], 3, axis=2) / 255
  foreground = image * mask + np.full(image.shape, 255) * (1 - mask) # From the paper ModNet, Colab Demo
  
  if return_comparison: # combine image, foreground, and alpha into one line
    combined = np.concatenate((image, foreground), axis=1)
    return Image.fromarray(np.uint8(combined))

  return foreground.astype(np.uint8)


def superimpose_background(foreground, background, alpha, overlay:bool = False):
    '''
    Change the background of any image given it's binary mask
    args:
        foreground: RGB image which has to be superimposed
        backgroud: Background of same shape
        alpha: B&W Mask image 
        overlay: Overlay background first
    '''
    if overlay:
        foreground = overlay_mask(foreground, alpha)
          
    foreground = (alpha * foreground) 
    
    background = (1.0 - alpha) * background 
    return (foreground + background).astype(np.uint8)
```

Below are my Original Image as Mask ans as you can see, there's blurriness in the image final segmented image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hope you get some idea from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001988/how-to-remove-background-of-images-in-python/63003020#63003020

Comment: @JeruLuke Morphology followed by Blur and stretch helped to some extent. Thank you.

Comment: In the answer linked above the author mentions morphological operations as an option.

Answer (score 0):

If mask is numpy array, you can set the mask threshold for removing low-confidence pixels like:

```
mask[mask<= 0.1] = 0
```

You can choose the threshold by yourself, based on your preferences and on your target data. But in this case line has no effect:

```
image * mask + np.full(image.shape, 255) * (1 - mask)
```

just try to use:

```
image * mask
```

If it doesn't work, for better visual effect you can just [blur](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) your mask with Gaussian/Bilateral/averaging filters

Comment: `image * mask` makes the image background black

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad