# Remove image background so that only the logo (usually some text) remains as png

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection

I would like to extract logos from golf balls for further image processing.
I have already tried different methods.

1. I wanted to use the grayscale value of the images to locate their location and then cut it out. Due to many different logos and a black border around the images, this method unfortunately failed.
2. as my next approach I thought that I first remove the black background and then repeat the procedure from 1. but also without success because there is a dark shadow in the lower left corner and this is also recognized as the "logo" with the grayscale method. Covering the border further on the outside is not a solution, because otherwise logos that are on the border will also be cut away or only half of them will be detected.
3. I used the edge detection algorithm Canny of the Open CV library. The detection looked very promising, but I was not able to extract only the logo from the detection, because the edge of the Golfball was also recognized.

Any solution is welcome. Please forgive my English. Also, I am quite a beginner in programming. Probably there is a very simple solution to my problem but I thank you in advance for your help.

Here are 2 example images first the type of images from which the logos should be extracted and then how the image should look like after extraction.

Thank you very much. Best regards T

[image]
[image]

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001988/how-to-remove-background-of-images-in-python

Comment: this image looks like a fairly easy example to work with. what's a hard example?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm not sure if that works but here is a link to a harder example: https://imgur.com/a/vEQTVH4
As you can see the logo is in the lower left corner where it is quite dark and it is also distorted due to the curvature of the ball

Comment: so... these pictures always have the ball fairly centered and illumination is always the same? these pictures look like a circular mask was applied (more or less exactly) and the background erased.

Comment: Yes exactly they basically look all the same. Unfortunately I do not know if some algorithms were applied in advance... I got the pictures like that with no further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially "adaptive" thresholding, except this approach doesn't *need* to threshold. It adapts to the illumination, leaving you with a perfectly fine grayscale image (or color, if extended to do that).

- median blur (large kernel size) to estimate ball/illumination
- division to normalize

illumination:

[image: illumination]

normalized (and scaled a bit):

[image: normalized]

thresholded with Otsu:

[image: otsu]

```py
def process(im, r=80):
    med = cv.medianBlur(im, 2*r+1)
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        normalized = np.where(med <= 1, 1, im.astype(np.float32) / med.astype(np.float32))
    return (normalized, med)

normalized, med = process(ball1, 80)
# imshow(med)
# imshow(normalized * 0.8)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold((normalized.clip(0,1) * 255).astype('u1'), 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
# imshow(thresh)
```

[image: ball2 illumination]

[image: ball2 normalized]

[image: ball2 otsu]

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive thresholding can do the trick.

[image]