# Vectorize Creating logical replacement along color channel

Tags: python, numpy, alpha-transparency

I have an image with a subject and a mostly white background. I am trying to create an alpha mask around the subject. Due to image compression artifacts, the white background is not entirely made up of (255,255,255) values for rgb values. I am trying to convert values such as (252,253,252) to (255,255,255).

My logic is as follows:

- If rgb values are within 2 of each other
- If  minimum rgb value is greater than 244
- Then set those rgb values to (255,255,255)

Here is my  inefficient code

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png') #400,400,3 in shape
for c_idx, column in enumerate(image):
    for r_idx, row in enumerate(column):
        if min(row) > 244 and max(row)-min(row)<=2:
            image[c_idx, r_idx] = [255,255,255]
```

I've attempted to make it more efficient by vectorizing with np.where. I've gotten it to check for the second condition but not the first condition.

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png') #400,400,3 in shape
image2 = np.where(image>=244), 255, image)
```

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001988/how-to-remove-background-of-images-in-python/63003020) algorithm, but the blending doesn't bring values down all of the way and I end up with integer overflows on the edges of the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ought to work

```
MAX_DIFF = 2
pxl_min = image.min(axis=0)
pxl_range = image.max(axis=0) - image.min(axis=0)
img2 = np.where(((pxl_min >= 244) & (pxl_range <= MAX_DIFF)), 255, image)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. It's must more efficient than I was able to build

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is similar in efficiency but slightly less efficient than the accepted solution (@Damian S.).

```
r = arr[:,:,0]
g = arr[:,:,1]
b = arr[:,:,2]

mask=(r+g+b>=744) & (np.maximum.reduce([r,g,b])-np.minimum.reduce([r,g,b]) <= 2)
arr[mask]=255
```

I compared the efficiency of this solution on arrays of 1000x1000x3 and the accepted one with 1,000 iterations and averaging the time to complete:

@Damian: Average: 0.0081s
My answer: Average: 0.0117